# runonuithread not called from asynctask doinbackground

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have a multiple `progressbars` which are added in a `fragment` and are updated in an `asynctask`. Now I want to replace and reset a `progressbar` when it is completed. I start a new `asynctask` to get the other related content and updated the `UI` in its `postexecute`. This is how I am doing it:

```
//my asynctask to update the progressbar
@Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // display the images in now playing
        while (ScheduleManager.isScheduleRunning) {
            Iterator iterator = nowPlayingMediaSet.entrySet().iterator();
            // set images on now playing
            for (int i = 0; i < btnImgNowPlaying.length && iterator.hasNext(); ++i) {
                Map.Entry mEntry = (Map.Entry) iterator.next();
                Show mShowNowPlaying = (Show) mEntry.getKey();
                // get show status
                mProgressStatus[i] = ScheduleManager
                        .getCurrentPlayingShowStatus(mShowNowPlaying);

                if (mProgressStatus[i] > 100) {             
                    this.newSchedule = (ChannelSchedule) mEntry
                            .getValue();
                    // get now playing show and replace it
                    this.newShow = ScheduleManager
                            .getNowPlayingShow(newSchedule.getListOfShows());
                    iterator.remove();
                    final int index = i;
                    FragmentTvGuide.GetParentActivity().runOnUiThread(
                            new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    new ScheduleListnerTask(
                                            btnImgNowPlaying[index])
                                            .execute(newShow
                                                    .getShowThumb()); //does not get invoked
                                }
                            });
                    this.newShowAdded = true;
                }           
                // Update the progress bar

            }
            if (newShowAdded){
                this.nowPlayingMediaSet.put(newShow, newSchedule);
                newShowAdded = false;
            }
            publishProgress(mProgressStatus);
            // sleep 1 second to show the progress
            try {
                Thread.sleep(20000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

//this is how get the parentactivity from fragment
//in onactivitycreated
context = getActivity();  //context is static
public static Activity GetParentActivity(){
        return (Activity) context;
    }
```

I do not know what has gone wrong here? Any ideas?

**EDIT**

This is the `asynctask` that I am trying to invoke:

```
public class ScheduleListnerTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    ImageButton btnImage;
    public ScheduleListnerTask(ImageButton btnImage){
        this.btnImage = btnImage;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String urldisplay = params[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        ImageLoader iLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        try {
            mIcon11 = iLoader.loadImageSync(urldisplay);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", "image download error");
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        btnImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: what does  `mProgressStatus[i] > 100`  mean ?

Comment: It holds the status in percentage of each `progressbar` which are there in the fragment

Comment: what's the maximum value of each progressbar?

Comment: Shouldnt it be `ProgressStatus[i]` **`>=`** `100` then?

Comment: I have tested it on `> 100` and the condition executes fine, but still the `asynctask` is not invoked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to call execute() on the new task...
EDIT: ok sorry, you didn't...

However I find starting a new asynctask out of another async task by running it on UIthread a little weired...Why don't you publish a progress at this point, and start the new task from onprogressupdated...?

Comment: I am calling `execute` on the new task.. And I cannot start the new task from `onprogressupdated` as I need to initialize the new task with parameters used in `doinbackground`

Comment: Ok, and can't you handle the things that you do in the new task in the current task? since you are already in a separate thread...?

Comment: I am downloading an image from a url and then updating the UI with that image. Please refer to the edit, I am updating it with the `asynctask` that I am trying to invoke

Comment: Well I think I would execute that image loading within the "original" task instead of starting a new task, then either publish the Bitmap as progress or use runOnUIThread just to set the image...
Although I don't really understand what you are doing in the original task. Nothing really looks like tasks that take long? So I assume there would be a much easier way. However this is just my suggestion :)

Comment: I suppose moving the task in one would make more sense. Thank you for this.